# when not specified how is number of columns determined

Tags: css, css-grid

With reference to [this code](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid_grid-area_named1)

```css
.item1 {
  grid-area: myArea;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'myArea myArea . . .';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
  <div class="item9">9</div>
</div>
```

How does the Grid Container know to put items 1 to 4 in the first row, and items 5 to 9 in the second?

Also, if I change the `grid-template-areas` specification from

```
grid-template-areas: 'myArea myArea . . .';
```

to

```
grid-template-areas: 'myArea myArea myArea myArea myArea . . .';
```

I still only get items 1 to 4 in the first row and the rest in the second. How does Grid Container know to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, in the code provided, the number of colums *is* specified.

When you use `grid-template-areas`, you tell the container to use a certain amount of space for the element that has the `grid-area` with the same name; when you see `grid-template-areas: 'myArea myArea . . .'` you are saying:

***Use two columns for the element `myArea`, then fill the remaining space with 3 other columns (which are the dots)***

When you see `grid-template-areas: 'myArea myArea myArea myArea myArea . . .';` you are saying basically:

***Use FIVE columns for the element `myArea`, then fill the remaining space with 3 other columns (which are the dots)***

So CSS Grid will divide the available space with the amount of columns you specify; the `grid-template-areas` lets you have a kind of a visual representation of your grid, where each 'item' divided by spaces is a column, so: `area area . . .` means:

***each row will have 5 columns, of which 'area' will use 2 of them***

You may also read more about Grid Areas and CSS Grid in general here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-template-areas

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'area . area2 area2';
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item.area {
  grid-area: area;
}

.grid-item.area2 {
  grid-area: area2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item area">Area 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item area2">Area 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
</div>
```